# selectInput as input in SQL query for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Working in R Shiny trying to use a selected value/string from a drop down menu as input in sql query. The problem is that I recieve the error message below. How would I get around this? The idea is that by selecting input from the dropdown menu (asset classes in this example) you'll be able to plot the corresponding return data in a line chart. I picked up the paste function from SO but don't get it to work with input$showDrop. Chart works fine when the entire query is hard-coded.

**Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

See code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)

ui <- shinyUI(
   fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Application Title"),

      ch <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SERVER;database=DATABASE;trusted_connection=true')
      showList <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT DISTINCT [Asset] FROM [TABLE] Where [Market] = 'US' ORDER BY [Asset]", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      selectInput("showDrop", "Select Asset", showList),

      plotOutput("cumReturn")
   ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$cumReturn <- renderPlot({
      ch <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SERVER;database=DATABASE;trusted_connection=true')
      returns <- sqlQuery(ch, paste("SELECT [Asof], [Data] FROM [TABLE] where [Market] = 'US' AND [Asset] = ", input$showDrop))
      dfx = xts(returns$Data-1, order.by=as.Date(returns$Asof))
      chart.CumReturns(dfx, main = "Accumulated return", wealth.index = TRUE, geometric = TRUE, legend.loc = NULL, ylog = TRUE,
                 colorset = (1:12), begin = c("first", "axis"))
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You need to include a sample data set that reproduces the error.

Comment: Not sure how that matters though, since it works fine if the query is "hard coded". Something happens when I try to use paste function with input$showDrop to make query dynamic. Don't even know what an "atomic vector" is.

Comment: It matters because your example is not reproducible. We need to run your code to debug it...

Comment: Solved it now because of two reasons: 1. I use paste0 instead of paste (don't know the difference of the two) 2. I forgot to include the ' symbols after "[Asset] ="

Anyways, the next issue is that I want to have two dropdown lists, one where I pick [Market] (now hard coded as 'US' but should be anything available) and one as above with [Asset] (each Market have a set of Assets). As of now the Asset-query and dropdown list is written in the ui and the returns is defined in server. How would you create one selectInput with Market with its value as input in the second selectInput (for Asset)?